# Method to detect browsers supporting HTML5 video autoplay

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, modernizr

I have done a couple of projects with video background, which plays automatically when loading page, and are only loaded when the device is not a mobile browser (those do not accept autoplay attribute on HTML5 videos, in that case just an image is loaded).

To detect this I use jQuery, as seen on here:

```
var isMobile = {
   Android: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);    },
   BlackBerry: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);    },
   iOS: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);    },
   Opera: function() {       return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);    },
   Windows: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);    },
   any: function() {        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());    }};

$(document).ready(function(){      
   if( isMobile.any() ) {
      $('.backgroundVideoC').append("<img alt= src='media/germannoload.jpg'/>");} 
   else{ 
      $('.backgroundVideoC').append("<video preload='auto' muted class='indexVideo' id='indexVideo'><source src='media/interactvid.webm' type='video/webm'><source src='media/interactvid.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>");
      $('#indexVideo').get(0).pause();}
```

This has worked properly for most of the cases, but I've seen that some Blackberry devices still load the video, even when those are mobile browsers and neither accept autoplay.

Is it recomendable to switch to Modernizr to detect whether is autoplay available, instead of checking this by jQuery? Does the jQuery method have any advantage from Modernizr autoplay detection?

Answer (score 2):

Modernizr v 3 (which is currently in prerelease at http://v3.modernizr.com/download) has a video autoplay detect.

Comment: Hope it is released soon

Comment: it is released. its just not an official version. the only thing stopping it right now is the website redesign

Comment: I have just tried Modernizr 3 Autoplay detection and it detects no-autoplay when opening from FF, wich DOES admit autoplay... is there any way of reporting this?

Comment: I have just reported on Github. Video autoplay only works fine on Opera. On FF/IE/Chrome theres a false negative

Comment: I don't think Modernizr can detect autoplay at this time. What it does detect is support for the autoplay attribute of the video element. Whether the browser respects the attribute setting is another question (which I don't think Modernizr can answer at time of writing).

Comment: @Vin. nope. you are wrong. checkout v3 of modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is accurately detecting the browser type and device type, which it might be given how you're going about doing it in your code sampe, you might have better success using a tool like UA-Parser.js (which is free). I have used this for my site and it is excellent in detecting browser types, mobile devices etc. I use it something like this:

```
    var parser = new UAParser();
    parser.setUA(navigator.userAgent);
    var result = parser.getResult();

    /*
        alert(result.browser.name); 
        alert(result.browser.version);
        alert(result.device.model);
        alert(result.device.type);
        alert(result.device.vendor);
        alert(result.os.name + ' - ' + result.os.version);
    */
```

There is virtually no browsser or device type it cannot accurately detect (at least based on my experience).

Comment: I am about to check this method, very grateful Randy.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr have some reliability issues in the video autoplay test, as pointed out here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1095

You can detect video autoplay support by checking if the paused status of a video element changes after it programmatically plays. This alone can return false negatives in some mobile browsers, so a Promise check should be added in order to cover these.

This method works in all major browsers (desktop and mobile), except for Android <= 4.0 and Windows Phone, where it returns a false negative.

Here is the detect function:

```js
var supports_video_autoplay = function(callback) {

  if (typeof callback !== "function") return false;

  var v = document.createElement("video");
  v.paused = true;
  var p = "play" in v && v.play();

  callback(!v.paused || ("Promise" in window && p instanceof Promise));

};
```

Usage:

```js
supports_video_autoplay(function(supported) {
  if (supported) {
    // video autoplay supported!
  } else {
    // no video autoplay support :(
  }
});
```

Live test: https://codepen.io/paulorely/pen/QveEGy

Answer (score 0):

Calling `video.play()` will generate a promise that will be rejected in non IE browsers. Use something like:

```
var p = video.play();

if (p) {
  p.catch(function() {
    //initiate fallback action
  });
}
```